# When using the z/OS High Level Assembler (HLASM), is there a way to return an equated symbol (defined via EQU) to the undefined state?

Tags: assembly, zos, mvs

In z/OS HLASM, I'm wondering if there is a way to "unequate" a symbol that was defined via the EQU instruction.  For example:

```
MyValue  EQU 999
...
         LHI R5,MyValue
...
MyValue  UNEQU     <===== or something that returns MyValue to the undefined state for the next statement in the assembly
```

I suppose this would be simiar in concept to a DROP following a USING to "scope" the relationship between a register and a DSECT, but in this case it would mean "this symbol is only valid within the scope between the EQU and the 'unEQU'."

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  I doubt this is possible.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a macro preprocessor that lets you `#undef MyValue` so it can have different values at different points in the source?  In many assemblers, `EQU` definitions are file-wide, and apply even to uses before the definition.  (Similar to how forward references to labels are also valid)

Comment: Sounds like an RFE. Probably would be a good one, but you'd need a good case. Maybe raise a SHARE languages requirement?

Comment: Maybe a good requirement or maybe I look at a different tool in the toolbox.  Perhaps SETC symbols?

Answer (score 3):

`EQU` creates a symbol and once defined its there for life.  Its not like a `#define` pragma in C.

IBM's Reference Manual for HLASM and the [EQU Instruction](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.asma400/equ.htm)

In essence you are creating a symbol it is entered and cannot be removed.  The manual does not specifically indicate this but given that once a symbol is defined with EQU it also cannot be changed.

For grins I tried a few variations and this was the result of trying to redefine the symbol ABC

```
  Active Usings: None                                                
  Loc  Object Code    Addr1 Addr2  Stmt   Source Statement           
000000                00000 00000     1 EQUTEST CSECT                
                      00001           2 ABC EQU 1                    
                      00002           3 ABC EQU 2                    
** ASMA043E Previously defined symbol - ABC                          
** ASMA435I Record 3 in USER1.TEST.SOURCE(EQUTEST) on volume: T70502
```

Comment: Yeah, that's where I was when I figured I'd just toss out a message in a bottle.  It's not a necessary function, just one that could have been used to simulate "scope" for an equated value.  Nothing ventured, nothing gained.